# caching and rendering blog posts in markdown in react

Tags: json, react.js, jsx, markdown

I'd like to know if I'm doing this badly or involving any antipatterns. Masterlist.json contains a list full of all of the posts that exist and should be fetched on the page. Post metadata is extracted with matter.

Would it be better to map to a `<Post />` component and to pass in all the information that way?

For more context [see the repository here](https://github.com/shrapnelnet/blog.shr4pnel.com-react).

```
import React from "react"
import matter from "gray-matter"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"

const sort = (a, b) => {
    if (a.data.date < b.data.date) {
        return 1
    }
    return -1
}

function getPosts() {
    return fetch("/posts/masterlist.json")
        .then((masterlist) => masterlist.json())
        .then((masterlistJSON) => {
            const posts = masterlistJSON.map((post) => `/posts/${post}`)
            const headers = new Headers()
            headers.set("Accept", "text/markdown")
            return Promise.all(
                posts.map((post) =>
                    fetch(post, { headers }).then((res) => res.text())
                )
            )
        })
        .then((postURLArrayMap) => {
            const parsedPosts = postURLArrayMap.map((post) => matter(post))
            parsedPosts.sort(sort)
            return parsedPosts
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
            return err
        })
}


export default function IndexPosts() {
    const { isPending, isError, data, error } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["posts"],
        queryFn: () => {
            return getPosts()
        },
    })

    if (isPending) {
        return <></>
    }

    if (isError) {
        return <h4>{error.message}</h4>
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h2 className="highlighted">articles</h2>
            <div id="articles">
                {
                    data.map((post, index) => (
                        <article key={index}>
                            <div className="card">
                                <img src="/graphics/anon.png" alt="tumblr anonymous grey face with sunglasses" height={80} width={80} />
                                <Link to={`/posts/${post.data.name}`}>{post.data.title}</Link>
                                <p>{new Date(post.data.date).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/shrapnelnet/blog.shr4pnel.com-react

Comment: in case any context is missing!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! When adding additional information you should [edit] your question  instead of adding a comment. I have added that information to your post. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).